# Initializing a pointer to structure with a constant array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Assuming I have two structures

```cpp
struct A
{ int x;
  int y;
};

struct B
{ int count;
  const A* list;
};
```

Now I want to initialize a compile time constant of `B`s.

```cpp
static const B Barray[] =
{ { 2,
    { { 7,8 }, {9,10} } // error
  },
  { 1,
    { { 30,40 } } // error
  },
};
```

The latter (of course) does not work since `list` is not declared as an array. But this is the way (old) APIs are often declared.

I could work around with a helper function which is basically just a cast:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr static const T* make_pointer(const T (&array)[])
{
    return array;
}

static const B Barray[] =
{ { 2,
    make_pointer<A>({ { 7,8 }, {9,10} })
  },
  { 1,
    make_pointer<A>({ { 30,40 } })
  }
};
```

But this is not that pretty.
Is it possible to initialize the data structure directly without a helper function?
(And, of course, without a named static constant for each A[].)

Comment: Do you need this to be available at compile time?  If not, the a `const std::vector<A>`  would work for you.  It lets you have a run time determined size, but you can't change that size after construction, and you can only change the elements in the vector.  If you don't want that, then you can even use a `const vector<const A>`.

Comment: `vector<>` won't help in any way since it also needs some static storage where it is bound to. Otherwise it is only temporary. So `vector` has no advantage over named static constants for each array.

Answer (score 3):

> But this is not that pretty.

Not only is that not pretty, but it's pretty much useless because the lifetime of the temporary array ends immediately after the initialisation of the static array, leaving the pointer dangling.

This would work, but it's far from pretty:

```
static const B Barray[] =
{ { 2,
    []{static A a[] { { 7,8 }, {9,10} }; return a; }(),
  },
  { 1,
    []{static A a[] { { 30,40 } }; return a; }(),
  },
};
```

Named static arrays are probably the best option for now

---

For what it's worth, there is a language feature for this in C99 and later: Compound literal. Popular compilers also implement this as a language extension in C++, but there is some variation in their implementation and crucially, for example GCC compound literals are temporary rather than static in C++ and thus not applicable for this use case.

There's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2174r0.html) to standardise, so it may be an option in a future C++ standard. Edit: I think that as proposed, compound literals in C++ would not have static storage, and if that interpretation is correct, then it would not be applicable to this use case.

Comment: Quick question: Would the example in the question work if the `make_pointer` function was marked `static`?

Comment: @Apple_Banana `make_pointer` is marked `static` in the question. It has no effect on the temporary argument passed into the function.

Comment: Ah ok nevermind. I know I didn't ask the question but I am interested but I don't understand this `[]{static A a[] { { 7,8 }, {9,10} }; return a; }()`

Comment: I specifically dont understand this bit `static A a[] ` because I haven't seen lamdas being declared like this

Comment: @Apple_Banana `static A a[]` is not a lambda. It is a local variable inside the lambda. The expression that you quoted in previous comment is sometimes called an "Immediately Invoked Function Expression".

Comment: okk I see it now. I was confused because it is missing that () that lambdas usually have after [].

Comment: And I just noticed that this does actually work as well `[]() {static A a[] { { 7,8 }, {9,10} }; return a; }()`

Comment: @Apple_Banana Yeah. The parameter list is optional for lambdas. No parameter list is same as empty parameter list.